# Setting up the probability distribution of Y = the number of empty bowls

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**Each of three balls are randomly placed into one of three bowls. Find the probability distribution for Y = the number of empty bowls.**

My first confusion is whether there are 9 balls in total or 3 that we must place into the bowls. Is it in the choice of words? I apologize for this as English is not my first language.

Then, I believe there are three options in which 1 bowl is empty. The first bowl is empty, or the second or the third bowl.

Beyond that, I am not sure how to find the probability of having 2 or 0 empty bowls.

Any help or hint is much appreciated,

Thank you.

Comment: I think there are three balls. There are $27=3^3$ outcomes overall. How many have no empty bowls? two empty bowls?

Comment: There are three bowls in total and the probability of having 0,1 or 2 empty bowls is what we want to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $3$ bowls and $3$ balls. Let for example $(3, 1, 2)$ be the outcome that the first ball went into bowl $3$, the second one into bowl $1$ and the third into bowl $2$.

We have $27$ possible outcomes:
$$
(1, 1, 1)\\
(1, 1, 2)\\
(1, 1, 3)\\
(1, 2, 1)\\
\cdots \\
(3, 3, 3)
$$
Let $N$ be the number of empty bowls after all three balls are placed. In order for us to have $N=2$, all balls need to have gone into the same bowl, which corresponds to the events $(1, 1, 1)$, $(2, 2, 2)$, $(3, 3, 3)$, i.e. $3$ events in total. Thus
$$
P(N=2) = \frac{3}{27}
$$
How many events correspond to $N=0$? Note this is equivalent to finding the number of ways to arrange $(1, 2, 3)$ – look at *the factorial* for a shortcut to finding this number.

Finally you can apply the fact that $P(N = 1) + P(N=2) + P(N=3) =1$.

---

That was the combinatorial method. You can do this faster, however, (although less safely, maybe) by multiplying probabilities: How does $N=2$ happen, for example: the first ball goes into any bowl. The second and third have to go into the same as the first one, thus
$$
P(N = 2) = 1 \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3}
$$
For $N=0$, the first ball goes into any bowl, the second ball has to go into one of the two remaining empty bowls, and the last ball has to go into the single remaining bowl, i.e.
$$
P(N=0) = 1 \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3}
$$

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation!